# Magento API, Return Orders with NULL values

Tags: api, magento

Using the magento api version 1 and soap.

Need to return all orders with 'coupon_code'=> NULL

The call I'm attempting:

```
$order_listAR = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.list', array(array('coupon_code'=>array('null'=>'null'))));
```

The ouput I want returned is this:

```
array(237) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(8) "complete"
    ["status"]=>
    string(8) "complete"
    ["coupon_code"]=> NULL
```

So far this seems to work properly, but I'm not sure if ('null'=>'null') is the proper way to find NULL values in the array. Can someone explain why this works, and, or if this is the correct syntax? I don't have any margin for error on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the syntax you use is correct to filter against `null`.

```
array(
    'coupon_code' => array(
        'null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'
    ) 
)
```

Magento maps<sup>*</sup> the API method `sales_order.list` to  `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api::items()`.

```
public function items($filters = null)
{
    :
    $collection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
    :
    if (is_array($filters)) {
        try {
            foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
                if (isset($this->_attributesMap['order'][$field])) {
                    $field = $this->_attributesMap['order'][$field];
                }

                $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    :
}
```

The `items()` method uses a `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` to fetch the orders for the API call. That collection is based on `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`, so

- `$collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value)`

from above essentially does call

- `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::addFieldToFilter()`

If you follow the latter, you'll hit `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::prepareSqlCondition()` in the end, params being

- `$fieldName = 'coupon_code'`
- `$condition = array('null' => 'null')`

Excerpt of that method:

```
public function prepareSqlCondition($fieldName, $condition)
{
    $conditionKeyMap = array(
        'eq'            => "{{fieldName}} = ?",
        :
        'notnull'       => "{{fieldName}} IS NOT NULL",
        'null'          => "{{fieldName}} IS NULL",
        : 
        'sneq'          => null
    );
    :

    $query = '';
    if (is_array($condition)) {
        :
        $key = key(array_intersect_key($condition, $conditionKeyMap));

        if (isset($condition['from']) || isset($condition['to'])) {
            :
        } elseif (array_key_exists($key, $conditionKeyMap)) {
            $value = $condition[$key];
            if (($key == 'seq') || ($key == 'sneq')) {
                :
            }
            $query = $this->_prepareQuotedSqlCondition($conditionKeyMap[$key], $value, $fieldName);
        } else {
            :
        }
    }
    :
}
```

In your case `_prepareQuotedSqlCondition()` will be called with

- `$text = '{{fieldName}} IS NULL'`
- `$value = 'null'`
- `$fieldName = 'coupon_code'`

which will result in `$query = 'coupon_code IS NULL'`.

If you take a closer look at the conversion method

```
protected function _prepareQuotedSqlCondition($text, $value, $fieldName)
{
    $sql = $this->quoteInto($text, $value);
    $sql = str_replace('{{fieldName}}', $fieldName, $sql);
    return $sql;
}
```

you'll also see, why the *value* of the `'null' => 'null'` key/value pair does not matter at all. That's because `$text` will be `'{{fieldName}} IS NULL'`, i.e. not containing any binding `?`.

Hence, there's nothing to replace for `_quoteInto()`^^

---

<sup>* see `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api.xml`</sup>

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the thorough explanation.